# Error: "accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" I used backgroundworker and still doesn't work

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a class that updates a progress bar on my GUI.
I used the backgroundWorker, both with the 'DoWork' and the 'RunWorkerCompleted' but both gave me the same error:

"accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

I thought that by using the method   "RunWorkerAsync()" it runs the commands on the GUI thread, so I guess I was wrong.

Here is the relevant code (tried both DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted):

```
this.backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted);




private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.progressBar1.PerformStep();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Program.handleException(Ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }
        }




     //public access from another class, that's my main problem
     //I don't activate the performStep() by pressing a button but its called by progress...
     //BTW, the while loop isn't efficient it is temporary..
         public void performStep()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
                        while (this.backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("worker2 is busy");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception Ex)
                    {
                        Program.handleException(Ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                    }
                }
```

Does anyone know why it still gives that error? (btw I tried to use delegates but found this way more convenient and recommended by MSDN so I would like to stick to this method..)

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Backgroundworker does not run the commands on the GUI thread. It runs them on a separate, dedicated thread.

To run things on the UI thread, you use the Invoke method on your control:

```
private void PerformStep()
{
    if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
    {
           progressBar1.Invoke(
             new MethodInvoker(() => progressBar1.PerformStep()));
    }
    else
    {
         progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
```

}